# How do I execute site code only if tag manager is properly loaded?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to ensure that GTM has loaded properly before running some javascript on my site. This JS code can't be moved into a GTM tag because it depends on variables that are unique to the framework.

```
if( typeof google_tag_manager !== 'undefined' ) {
  //I tried running my code here
}
```

When I tested what was posted above, the code inside the block wouldn't run, but checking the value of google_tag_manager in the console indicated that it was an object and not undefined. What's the best way to ensure that GTM has loaded before running some js code?

Answer (score 1):

> This JS code can't be moved into a GTM tag because it depends on
>   variables that are unique to the framework.

As it stands that does not sound like a real caveat. You could push the variables to the dataLayer and trigger your tag with a custom event:

```
dataLayer.push({
'data' : myUniqeVars,
'event' : 'mySpecialEvent'
});
```

or even access the variables as global javascript variables.

Alternatively you could set a global javascript variable (e.g. window.startMyTag=true) in a custom html tag that is fired on pageview (the earliest point at which the GTM code is certainly loaded) and listen for that, although that would be a horrible solution (and the reason you need a listener is that GTM code is loaded asychronously; this seems to be the reason why your code does not fire and you still see the gtm_tag_manager on the console, because the console only becomes available IIRC after the DOM is loaded).

Or you might set up a listener for changes in the dataLayer - when GTM fires one of the first things it does is to put key/value pair "event:gtm.js" on the dataLayer, and you could use that to fire your code (not the best idea possibly - if you have a machine that controls states you might not want to mess with the states from outside, but as long as your only listing you should be safe. Don't simply overwrite the push method of the dataLayer though to watch for GTM events, because that's what GTM itself already does and it will break if you overwrite the already modified method).

I'd be curious why you think you cannot run your code from within GTM, so if you can give an example I'd be really grateful.

Comment: The context is a SaaS ecommerce platform. For example on the category page we want to send the ecommerce data related to a product when it is clicked on. Looking at it more, you might be right, it could be modified to work within a tag.

Comment: If the values exist as JS variables somewhere in the global scope and you have GTM code in the same page then it's almost certain that you can get your code to work from within a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Firing custom js using window.onload ensures that GTM has loaded